# How to count people in JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file with users:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Michael",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "like": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "like": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "like": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "like": 1
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "Antony",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "like": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "like": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "like": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "like": 1
            }
        ]

    },
...
```

And I need to count all users with likes, so after this I need to have an array like this:

> userWithlikes[0] = 2,
>
> userWithlikes[1] = 2,
>
> userWithlikes[2] = 3, ...

I can to calculate how many users I have:
var allUsers = thumbsUp_data.length;

All data from JSON file in "thumbsUp_data".

Help, How do I count all users and display the number of likes a data array?

Comment: Have you made an attempt at this which you have an issue with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this pretty easily using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Here's an example

```js
var users = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Michael",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "like": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "like": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "like": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "like": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "Antony",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "like": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "like": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "like": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "like": 1
            }
        ]
    }
];

var usersWithLikes = users.map(function(user) {
    return user.users.filter(function(value) {
        return value.like === 1;    
    }).length;
});

console.log(usersWithLikes);
```